# In Perl, how do I send CGI parameters on the command line?

Tags: perl, parameters, cgi, command-line-arguments

Normally i get the data from a webpage but i want to send it from the command line to facilitate debugging.

To get the data i do something like:

```
my $query = new CGI;
my $username = $query->param("the_username");
```

this doesn't seem to work:

```
$ ./script.pl the_username=user1
```

#### EDIT:

Actually the above works. The `if` statement that checked `$username` was wrong (using `==` instead of `eq`).

Comment: Do you have `use CGI;` in your script (note the caps)? Are you using `$query = new CGI; print $query->param("the_username")` or something else?

Comment: There, i fixed some syntax. yes i have use CGI;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I found out long time ago, you can indeed pass query string parameters to a script using [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI). I am not recommending this as a preferred debugging method (better to have replicable stuff saved in files which are then directed to the `STDIN` of the script), however, it does work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;

use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $param_name = 'the_username';

printf(
    "The value of '%s' is '%s'.\n",
    $param_name, $cgi->param($param_name)
);
```

Output:

```
$ ./t.pl the_username=yadayada
The value of 'the_username' is 'yadayada'.
```

Comment: Thanks, your right. i was just using incorrect syntax when checking if it was sent.

Answer (score 7):

CGI reads the variables from standard input.

See this part of the CGI.pm documentation:

http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#DEBUGGING

Comment: Yeah, it's almost like a manual about how to do CGI with Perl ;)