# CGI Commandline Args Disappearing

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a cgi script that calls another cgi script.

main_script.cgi script looks like this:

```
print qx/child_script.cgi arg1=foo arg2=bar/;
```

child_script.cgi looks something like this:

```
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;
my $query = CGI->new;
warn Dumper($query);
```

If I do ./main_script.cgi in the shell, I get:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             '.parameters' => [
                                'arg1',
                                'arg2'
                              ],
             'use_tempfile' => 1,
             '.charset' => 'ISO-8859-1',
             '.fieldnames' => {},
             'param' => {
                          'arg1' => [
                                        'foo'
                                    ],
                          'arg2' => [
                                        'bar'
                                    ]
                        },
             'escape' => 1
           }, 'CGI' );
```

But if I visit myhost.com/main_script.cgi in the browser, the output is:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             '.parameters' => [],
             'use_tempfile' => 1,
             '.charset' => 'ISO-8859-1',
             '.fieldnames' => {},
             'param' => {},
             'escape' => 1
           }, 'CGI' );
```

Comment: @Miller, I may not be understanding what you mean, but CGI objects do, by default, include arguments from the command line - see here: http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#DEBUGGING

Comment: CGI reads the variables from standard input, which is why it works fine if you call it from command line, and not from browser. [Also see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403184/in-perl-how-do-i-send-cgi-parameters-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your secondary script is inheriting `%ENV` from your first script.  If `CGI` sees a `REQUEST_METHOD` it ignores the commandline parameters and instead loads things from the `QUERY_STRING`, etc.

To fix this, you must first localize the `%ENV` and delete the `REQUEST_METHOD`.

The following demonstrates this:

`part1.pl`

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use Data::Dump;

my $q = CGI->new;

print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
dd $q;

# Localize the REQUEST_METHOD so that the secondary process doesn't see it.
my $text = do {
    local $ENV{REQUEST_METHOD};
    qx(perl part2.pl arg1=val1 arg2=val2);
};

print $text;
```

`part2.pl`

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use Data::Dump;

my $q = CGI->new;

print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
dd $q;
```

Accessing `http://localhost/cgi-bin/part1.pl?a=1&b=2` displays the following:

```
bless({
  ".charset"     => "ISO-8859-1",
  ".fieldnames"  => {},
  ".parameters"  => ["a", "b"],
  "escape"       => 1,
  "param"        => { a => [1], b => [2] },
  "use_tempfile" => 1,
}, "CGI")
Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

bless({
  ".charset"     => "ISO-8859-1",
  ".fieldnames"  => {},
  ".parameters"  => ["arg1", "arg2"],
  "escape"       => 1,
  "param"        => { arg1 => ["val1"], arg2 => ["val2"] },
  "use_tempfile" => 1,
}, "CGI")
```